# Laptop won't charge nor power on with plug in

Tags: laptop, charging, acdsee

The laptop in question is an European Acer Aspire V3-771G, bought in October 2014. 
I haven't been using it a lot for the last year since I bought a desktop pc, but I need it as I'm heading off the country.

I recently found out that despite a working battery, my laptop won't turn on when it's only powered up by the plug, or charge my battery as fast as it usually did in the past. I've tested my components thanks to my roommate's laptop as he exactly has the same model. The laptop starts with a full battery.

In short:
-The battery is still working. When plugged in my roommate's laptop, it's charging correctly and isn't showing anything wrong. (despite the lowered battery life after two years, but I'm used to this)

-The power cord is still working. Tested with the other laptop.

-My laptop is still working, as it powers on just fine when the battery's been charged with my roommate's laptop.

-What's weird is that despite the laptop not powering on when it's plugged without the battery, it still charges but very slowly. Example: I leave my laptop plugged 24/7, and when the battery dies after two hours, I can power it on again later (usually one day or two) and have juice for another two hours.

Please note that since August 2015, I used an outlet converter since I'm now living in North America, so I've gone from 220v to 110v. I don't know if it may be the source of the problem or not.

I'm not a hardware expert, so I'd gladly use your help folks! 
What components aren't working? Must they be replaced/fixed?

What's the cause of this trouble?

Comment: Just because the battery is good and the charger is good doens't mean the device's charging circuit is good

Comment: I think you've ruled out the easy options: battery and charger; those you could've replaced yourself. Your best bet now is to give it to a professional to repair it.

Comment: You might try recalibrating the charger; see http://www.tomsguide.com/faq/id-2342991/calibrate-battery-windows-laptops.html. There's no assurance this will help, but it's simple and free, so worth a try.